# x-www-form-urlencoded api calls with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to make the following api call with axios but i am not really sure how to proceed. I was able to do it in postman but i am falling with axios even though it returns a 200 OK status it doesnt return any of the data i need.

I took all of this from the postman post i made:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "./axios-auth.js";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        username: null,
        password: null,
    },
    actions: {
        login(authData) {
          console.log(authData);
            axios
              .post("/?target=&auth_id=&ap_name=", {
                login: "login",
                username: authData.username,
                password: authData.password,

              },
              {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                  'Origin': 'http://10.000.000.01:8080',
                  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36',
                  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                  'Referer': 'http://10.000.000.01:8080/',
                  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                  'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              }})
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
              })
              .catch(error => console.log(error));

          },
    },

});
```

Comment: what's the response/content of `res`

Comment: nothing is shown but it says it received the call with a 200 ok response.

Comment: it's hard to tell with so little information, but you can probably safely remove all the header stuff (except the cache control/max-age). Axios uses it's own headers